# How to calculate probability of an event occurring on plot level?

Tags: r

I am working with tree data and trying to calculate the annual probability of harvesting occurring on plot level but am struggling a bit with the concept. I have individual tree data in a format similiar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(plot=c("A","A","B","B","C"),
                 tree=c(1,1,2,3,4),
                 year1=c(2000,2000,2005,2005,2007),
                 year2=c(2002,2004,2010,2010,2014),
                 averageInterval=c(3,3,5,5,7)
                 harvest=c(0,1,1,1,0))
```

Based of of this data, I would like to calculate the annual probability of `harvest` happening on a `plot` level.

Comment: This is a statistics question rather than a programming question. You will get better answers over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), the statistics equivalent of Stack Overflow. I have voted to migrate your question over there.

Comment: what does `year1` and `year2` refer to? Is it start and end point of a time window in which the `harvest` of a specific `tree` on a specific `plot` took place (or did not take place)? And what is `averageInterval`? is this a only plot specific characteristic

Comment: @uke the years are the sampling intervals, so it means that in one of the years between ```year1``` and ```year2``` the sampling was conducted

Comment: why wouldn't people just record the date of sampling precisely?

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna make a guess here, and assume that by probability you just mean the proportion of harvests over the total number of rows in each plot. That seems a job for tapply:

```
prob <- tapply(df$harvest, df$plot, function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)})
```

Another alternative is using `aggregate()` and `group_by()`, the latter from the `dplyr` package but I tend to use them for more complex operations with multiple columns.

Comment: fyi, as of `R` 4.1.0, it is possible to natively use `\(x) {}` instead of `function(x) {}`. Moreover, we do not need the curly parenthesis (here).